# Highcharts: show multiple days data on same chart making them overlpa each other to comparison

Tags: highcharts

I have a set of N values for each day logged from a webserver (N is not always the same each day, but this is not relevant).
I need to show a comparison chart with values from multiple days, eg:

1. today (16/01/2017)
2. yeasterday (15/01/2017)
3. a month ago (15/12/2016)

To do that, I though about something similar to:

- the 3) as 'area chart'
- the 2) as 'dotted line chart'
- the 1) as 'continue line chart'

This is easy, but now I have a problem: if I declare X axis as 'datetime' obviously the 3 chart series are not 'overlapped' because each one represent a different day along datetime axis.
Instead **I need them to overlalp**, so user can quickly compare values.
Ho can I do that?
Categorized X axis? Multiple X axes

Comment: You can do category xAxis. Or, you can set all the timestamps of your data to some arbitrary value. Your data set and usage would dictate what would be best - I can see case where you may want to see data for a week/prior week/some other week. In that case you would need to normalize your start date for each series to some pre-determined value.

Comment: Multiple timestamp axes seem to be fine for you scenario: http://jsfiddle.net/kPqKW/

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to handle this with a single `datetime` axis, using a common `pointStart` and `poiintInterval` for all series (set in the `plotOptions`).

This plots each series on the same date from a technical standpoint, but with some basic formatting accomplishes the goal of viewing each date along the same time axis.

The benefits to this approach over categories and using multiple axes, IMO, are

- Makes full use of the `datetime` axis type features
- Does not require any additional overhead for adding more series - this works just as well with 2 or 20 series

Example fiddles:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/b3t7ueam/ (two dates)
- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/hbfap864/ (many dates)

Example Output:

[image]